# Spring-Boot: Create instances of custom annoated classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, annotations, java-11

For a project, I'm trying to collect all the classes for a specific custom annotation and create it's instances. Or use Spring-Boot instances created in it's context.

Here is the custom annotation:

```
public @interface MyAnnotation {
   String name();
}
```

Here are the classes using this annotation in various packages:

In `com.my.project.package1`

```
@MyAnnotation(name = "package_1_impl")
public class Package1Impl {}
```

In `com.my.project.package2`

```
@MyAnnotation(name = "package_2_impl")
public class Package2mpl {}
```

Now, I would like collect all these implementation instances and use them for strategy pattern for example.

So, I want to do something like the following. The following is just my assumption that such a thing exists.

`Option#1` In my Service class: `MyAnnotationService.java`:

```
@Service
@Singleton
class MyAnnotationService {
   
     public MyAnnotationService() {
         List<String> classNamesToLoad = SpringSomething.findWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
         
         for (String cls : classNamesToLoad) {
           createNewInstance(cls);
         }
 
     }
}
```

`Option#2` In my Service class: `MyAnnotationService.java`:

```
@Service
@Singleton
class MyAnnotationService {
   
     public MyAnnotationService() {
         Map<String, Object> objectsCreatedBySpring = SpringSomething.findWithAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class);
     }
}
```

I'm not sure where and what to look for to achieve this. Or if it's even possible.

Comment: Use [`getBeansWithAnnotation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29)

Comment: Does this mean I need to annotate `Package1Impl` and `Package2Impl` with `@Bean` ? But Bean is applied on a method, right?

Comment: They are already managed by Spring, right? I mean they have an annotation of `@Componenet` or just your custom one?

Comment: Just the custom one at the moment.

Comment: Add the `@Component` annotation so they are managed by Spring. Then from the  `ApplicationContext` you can get all the beans, and even specific beans from an annotation. Try it and I will write an answer for your question.

Comment: But using `@Component` would suggest it can be used to `@Autowire`, right? What if I don't want it to be autowired, but only be stored in the context for one specific service to use.

Comment: Yes you are right, spring will scan application for classes annotated with @Component, instantiate them and inject any specified dependencies into them
Inject them wherever needed. `@Bean` is used to explicitly declare a single bean, rather than letting Spring do it automatically as above. It decouples the declaration of the bean from the class definition, and lets you create and configure beans exactly how you choose.

Comment: Okay, so if I have to use `@Component` then it'd autowired. no other way. Okay. thanks for the explanation. If you answer the question, I can mark it as the correct one

Comment: Does it solve your issue? Otherwise we must find a solution :)

Comment: Well, I was looking for something that loads my custom annotation classes without having to use @Component. But maybe it's not possible to what I want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238432/discussion-between-aris-and-user2354302).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution for this.

Add the [`@Component`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-annotation) annotation so your classes are managed by Spring. Then from the [`ApplicationContext`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-application-context), you can get all the beans and even specific beans from an annotation with [getBeansWithAnnotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/ListableBeanFactory.html#getBeansWithAnnotation%28java.lang.Class%29).

Example

```
Map<String,Object> beans = applicationContext.getBeansWithAnnotation(Foo.class);
```

Comment: Is possible to inject the ApplicationContext in a `@Service` class?

Comment: yes `@Autowired private ApplicationContext applicationContext;`

Comment: Throws NPE. Anything I need to do extra to access the ApplicationContext?

Comment: It had to be a autowired in the constructor and not as a class variable. Anyway, thank you

Comment: Ohh ok, and I just opened a chat room, haha. It's ok, I am happy that I helped